# after running the code i am getting (TypeError: Json2Excel.run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data')

Tags: python

```
from json2excel import Json2Excel

import json

from pprint import pprint
# read the json file

data = json.loads(open('E:/jsonfiles/7.json').read())

# print(data)

print("Checking if keyword exists in JSON")

if "attributes" in data:
        
     print('key exits in 7.json data' )
        
     pprint(data['attributes'])
     print(Json2Excel.run('.json'))
        
                   
else:
     
     print("Key doesn't exist in JSON data")
```

Comment: Did you try `Json2Excel.run(data)`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create an object with the column names:

   ```
   json2excel = Json2Excel(head_name_cols=data[0].keys())
   ```
2. Then call `run()` with the data:

   ```
   print(json2excel(data))
   ```

But don't do this. Just use the standard [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead. It is well documented and easy to use.